# Stuck on Interpreting Declaration of Variables in PL/SQL Script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Okay so I have been asked to validate some PL/SQL code that was sent to me and I am having trouble doing so. After searching around quite a bit before asking this question, I could not find an answer. This may be a relatively easy question to answer depending on if I've asked it correctly so here it is...

In short, I'm trying to figure out if the following declaration statement contains or is pointing to an external package? The code following the variable declarations references these variables but will not work when I want to run it indicating that there is something I'm missing in order to do so. What is the 'gamejobs.param('01'),('02'), ect..'?

```
DECLARE
x_currentGame varchar2(15) := gamejobs.param('01');
x_gameYear varchar2(4) := gamejobs.param('02');
x_gameCode varchar2(4) := gamejobs.param('03');
x_gameID varchar2(9) := gamejobs.param('04');
```

Comment: `gamejobs` may be a package identifier or a scheme identifier.

Comment: I would guess that `gamejobs` is a package and `param` is either a function within that package or a collection.  But that's a guess.  `gamejobs` could be the schema name and `param` could be a function defined in that schema.  It's odd that, apparently, `x_gameYear`, `x_gameCode`, and `x_gameID` are being assigned the same value, that makes me suspect that you've made a mistake copying and pasting some code.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It did turn out to be a package identifier.

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you for your help! It turned out that the package contained a function within it. The package was not sent to me along with the script so I could not execute it. I appreciate your response.